# OpenGL ES 2. При повороте экрана телефона исчезают все рисуемые объекты

Tags: java, android, opengl, opengles

Возникла такая проблема: при смене ориентации с портретной на альбомную все рисуемые объекты исчезают и остается одна заливка. 
Рисую на GLSurfaceView используя функции OpenGL ES 2.0
Метод onSurfaceChange выглядит следующим образом:

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 arg0, int width, int height) {
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    GraphicTricks.initializeFrustumMatrix(width, height);
    GraphicTricks.bindMatrixForColorShader();
}
```

В методе initializeFrustumMatrix(width, height) я создаю матрицу проекций, вот ее код:

```
public static void initializeFrustumMatrix(int width, int height) {
    // Отношение большей стороны телефона к меньшей
    float ratio = 1.0f;
    // Координаты сторон near границы
    // Ширина и высота near границы равна 2
    float left = -1.0f;
    float right = 1.0f;
    float bottom = -1.0f;
    float top = 1.0f;
    // Расстояние от камеры до ближайшей границы
    float near = 1.0f;
    // Расстояние от камеры до дальнейшей границы
    float far = 8.0f;

    if (width > height) {
        ratio = (float) width / height;
        left *= ratio;
        right *= ratio;
    } else {
        ratio = (float) height / width;
        bottom *= ratio;
        top *= ratio;
    }

    Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far);
}
```

Т.е. матрица записывается в float[16] массив mProjectionMatrix
Ну и последний метод, bindMatrixForColorShader() выглядит так:

```
public static void bindMatrixForColorShader() {
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mMatrix, 0);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uMatrixLocationColor, 1, false, mMatrix, 0);
}
```

Т.е. просто перемножает все матрицы и связывает результат с шейдером.
Все работает хорошо, пока я не поверну экран телефона, при повороте все рисуемые объекты исчезают...
Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо использовать `onSaveInstanceState` и `onRestoreInstanceState`.

Comment: Т.е. при смене ориентации все, что было создано в onSurfaceCreated пропадает?

Comment: ПОжалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.

Answer (score 1):

Переопределите метод `onSurfaceCreated` и выполните в нем отрисовку. И ещё добавьте в тэг активности в манифест

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: Метод onSurfaceCreated переопределен, в нем я заполняю массив вершин, передаю его в буфер, создаю программу из шейдеров, получаю положения переменных из шейдеров + задаю матрицу вида.

Comment: Метод onDrawFrame также переопределен, в нем происходит непосредственно отрисовка, все работает, пока телефон в портретной ориентации...